# Как зафиксировать календарь в развернутом виде в <input type='date' >?

Tags: html

Заказчик хочет чтобы календарь был развернут всегда, я вот что не могу придумать 
как это сделать, может кто подскажет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее всем спасибо)

Comment: Попробуйте сделать елементу фокус `window.setTimeout('document.getElementById("myCalendar").focus();',100);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно написал @Node_pro такой возможности в HTML нет. Об этом также написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24980193/8119704). В этом ответе есть ссылка на то, как можно решить вашу проблему. Для возможной с помощью js-плагина реализации можно воспользоваться например библиотекой [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/). Пример реализации:

```js
$(function() {
  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);
  $('.date').datepicker({
    altField: $('.date').data('altfield'),
    format: 'dd.MM.yyyy'
  });
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="startdate" id="somedate" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="date" data-altfield="#somedate"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Такой возможности на HTML нет. Для того, чтобы реализовать подобное необходимо использовать js-плагин. Например [DatePicker](https://www.google.com/?q=datepicker)